# mvvm - prismv2 - INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-2

Since this is so long and prolapsed and really doesnt ask a coherent question:

1: what is the proper way to implement subproperties of a primary object in a viewmodel?

2: Has anyone found a way to fix the delegatecommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged issue? or do I need to fix it myself until MS does?

*For the rest of the story...continue on.*

In my viewmodel i have a doctor  object property that is tied to my Model.Doctor, which is an EF POCO object. I have onPropertyChanged("Doctor") in the setter as such:

```
       Private Property Doctor() As Model.Doctor
            Get
                Return _objDoctor
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As Model.Doctor)
                _objDoctor = Value
                OnPropertyChanged("Doctor")
            End Set
        End Property
```

The only time OnPropertyChanged fires if the WHOLE object changes. This wouldnt be a problem except that I need to know when the properties of doctor changes, so that I can enable other controls on my form(save button for example). I have tried to implement it in this way:

```
Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return _objDoctor.FirstName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _objDoctor.FirstName = Value
            OnPropertyChanged("Doctor")
        End Set
    End Property
```

this is taken from the XAMLPowerToys controls from Karl Shifflet, so i have to assume that its correct. But for the life of me I cant get it to work.

I have included PRISM in here because I am using a unity container to instantiate my view and it IS a singleton. I am getting change notification to the viewmodel via eventaggregator that then populates Doctor with the new value. The reason I am doing all this is because of PRISM's DelegateCommand. So maybe that is my real issue.

It appears that there is a bug in DelegateCommand that does not fire the RaiseCanExecuteChanged method on the commands that implement it and therefore needs to be fired manually. I have the code for that in my onPropertyChangedEventHandler. Of course this isnt implemented through the ICommand interface either so I have to break and make my properties DelegateCommand(of X) so that I have access to RaiseCanExecuteChanged of each command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2: Has anyone found a way to fix the
>   delegatecommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged
>   issue? or do I need to fix it myself
>   until MS does?

Use Josh Smith's [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) instead of the DelegateCommand.  It fixes the issue with CanExecute commands not being raised, and doesn't leak memory like the DelegateCommand:

*"It delegates the event subscription to the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event. This ensures that the WPF commanding infrastructure asks all RelayCommand objects if they can execute whenever it asks the built-in commands."*

Comment: yep, I decided to go that route. Heck I may even dump prism altogether for MEF...hehe thanks

Answer (score 0):

About 2: There is no bug to fix by Microsoft, since it is by design that you have to explicitely tell the command to re-evaluate itself. Of course you may disagree with their decision.

If you want to have the DelegateCommands re-evaluate whenever RaiseCanExecuteChanged is fired, see http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=47338